# How to encode JSON as request parameter using Alamofire and AlamofireObjectMapper

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I have a question about doing POST, PATCH, and PUT requests when using Alamofire and AlamofireObjectMapper. For example, lets say that I am doing a POST request to to send a object to a server. Can I pass a mapping as parameters for the request. Does it work similar to how RestKit encodes parameters into the body of the request as JSON?

Comment: Yes, you should implement [`Mappable`](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper#the-basics) protocol for your model objects. Alamofire will then smartly convert the object into JSON upon sending it to the server.

Comment: Can you give a code snippet of what that would like? I was reading the documentation, but it only shows examples for GET requests.